# LibGDX / Box2D: How to keep track of active Contacts between bodies?

Tags: libgdx, box2d

I'm making a 2D (side view) car game with LibGDX using Box2D. The car has a front wheel and a rear wheel and it's "AWD". I would like to render a dust effect to each point where a wheel touches the ground when the player is "burning rubber". To do this, my plan was to

1. Implement ContactListener, and in beginContact(Contact contact) method find the Contacts where one of the fixtures is ground and the other one a wheel of the car.
2. Save these Contacts to a (wheel-specific) array, which is supposed to contain the active Contacts of the wheel (the wheel can touch the ground in multiple points, hence an array is required).
3. During each render call, for each Contact in each wheel's array: Get the contact position, and calculate velocity difference between the wheel body and the ground body at that position. If the length of the velocity difference vector is greater than a certain threshold, then draw the dust effect (using the velocity difference vector to define the speed and angle of the dust particles).
4. When endContact(Contact contact) of my ContactListener is called, remove contact from the array.

The problem is that LibGDX appears to use the SAME Contact instance for every Box2D contact, rewriting the existing Contact even if it's still active! This means, for example, that if the rear wheel touches the ground first and the front wheel after that, the Contact instance I saved to the rear wheel's contact array gets overwritten with front wheel's contact properties. Another problem is that when I receive endContact, I don't know which Contact really ended.

Have I understood something wrong, or is this how LibGDX is supposed to behave? Is it possible to somehow adjust this behavior, or is there an easy workaround?

(One option that comes to my mind is to keep listening to beginContact and endContact calls and just keep track of the ground bodies/fixtures that are touching each wheel, but then I would have to calculate the contact points manually each frame, which sounds somewhat difficult, expensive, and redundant - because Box2D anyway calculates it at each world step).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can create a MyContactListener implementing the ContactListener class.

The MyContactListener class contains a MyContactInventory object which is a Singleton object containing your Contact Array and a couple of convenient method:

- addContact
- removeContact

The beginContact and endContact add/remove Contacts to your Array using the convenient methods above.

Then you call world.setContactListener( new MyContactListener());

Hope it helps!

Comment: This sounds a lot like what I have already, but the problem is when I add a Contact instance to my array, that same instance gets "overwritten" by LibGDX when a new contact occurs in the Box2D world. So how can I access the original contact data (e.g. position) then?

Comment: wrap your array in a Singleton class.That way whenever you add a contact it uses the existing instance.

Comment: Hmm, I have not used Singletons before so I'll have to look into that. But I cannot really see how it could work. For example: Let's say front wheel contact occurs first, beginContact is called with com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.Contact@53b05f10 as a parameter. 100 ms later rear wheel contact occurs => LibGDX modifies the Contact@53b05f10 so that it now contains rear wheel contact data (incl. position). No matter in what way I have stored the original Contact instance in the first place, how could it know the front wheel contact position 200 ms after the contact? What keeps it updated?